# Python - Trying to insert dictionaries into postgres database, seeing keyerror

Tags: python, json, postgresql

Trying to insert dictionaries into postgres database, seeing error: 
 KeyError: 'longPositionPercentage'

```
url = 'https://demo-api.example.com/gateway/deal/example?'
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    result=response.json()
    #print(result)
    for item in result['clientSentiments']:
            print(item)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sentiment_history
                      (client_sentiment_long,client_sentiment_short,marketid) 
                      VALUES (%(longPositionPercentage)s,
                              %(shortPositionPercentage)s,
                              %(marketId)s,);""",result)
    conn.commit()
    print(datetime.now(), cursor.rowcount, "record inserted/updated")
     # Close the connection
    conn.close()
```

Example of the dictionaries I am trying to save to database:

```
{u'shortPositionPercentage': 35.0, u'longPositionPercentage': 65.0, u'marketId': u'2YRTND'}
{u'shortPositionPercentage': 36.0, u'longPositionPercentage': 64.0, u'marketId': u'SE30'}
{u'shortPositionPercentage': 30.0, u'longPositionPercentage': 70.0, u'marketId': u'USDHUF'}
{u'shortPositionPercentage': 17.0, u'longPositionPercentage': 83.0, u'marketId': u'ETHXBT'}
```

Comment: Why does your title mention Python 2?

Comment: I am coding python 2.7

Comment: You're using `print` like a function though, which is one of the most noticeable differences between Python 2 and 3...

Comment: Apologies I am just learning here. Do you know why I am seeing the keyerror?

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Just this:     cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sentiment_history(client_sentiment_long,client_sentiment_short,marketid) VALUES (%(longPositionPercentage)s,%(shortPositionPercentage)s,%(marketId)s,);""",result)
KeyError: 'longPositionPercentage'

Comment: I have tried using executemany, but that throws up this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206100/discussion-between-stein-and-amc).

Answer (score 0):

Try with some like this :

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import json


conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='yyy' user='yyy' host='yyyy' password='yyyy'")
cur = conn.cursor()

f='{"clientSentiments": [{"shortPositionPercentage": 35.0, "longPositionPercentage": 65.0, "marketId": "2YRTND"}, {"shortPositionPercentage": 35.0, "longPositionPercentage": 65.0, "marketId": "SE30"}]}'
data = json.loads(f)

for k in data['clientSentiments']:
  columns = ['client_sentiment_long','client_sentiment_short','marketid']
  columns = ",".join([str(s) for s in list(columns)])
  values = ",".join(["'"+str(s)+"'" for s in list(k.values())])
  sql = "INSERT INTO sentiment_history (%s)  VALUES  (%s) " % (columns , values)
  print(sql)
  cur.execute(sql)

conn.commit() 
conn.close()
```

Comment: Don't do this.  Use psycopg2 for string substitution.  Your method leaves the code open to sql injection and a host of issues dealing with special characters.

Comment: @Jeremy then how ?